# Sandisk Extreme USB 3.0 64GB Write speed drops

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, usb-3

The problem started about a week ago. My Sandisk USB drive normally writes at 150-200MB/s (SSD to USB drive) but all of a sudden the write speed dropped to 5-10MB/s.

The problem keeps occurring: it starts out at a normal speed but drops quite fast to the lower speed.

Reading speed is the same as always.

USB port works fine (other drives still write at the same speed).
The problem occurs on multiple computers but my laptop has it the worst (Samsung EVO 840 SSD, i7, 8GB RAM).

I already tried formatting (quick and full) without improvement. 
HD Tune error check came out clean and the benchmark gave 175MB/s average transfer speed so the drive isn't faulty.

Comment: What types of files are you writing? a bunch of smaller files will typically take much longer then one big file... Also, what is the source? another SSD or a regular HDD?

Comment: What type of files are you transferring ? Some file types take a lot of time.

Comment: Large video files mostly. Same as before the drop in speeds so the files are not the problem.

Source (laptop) is SSD.

Comment: Since it's an SSD inside, it's probably the lack of TRIM working.  Unfortunately, I haven't figured out how to deal with this yet.

Comment: @RussellUhl: The slow write speed issue is affecting his USB flash drive, not the SSD in his laptop.

Comment: @Karan I know.  That usb drive is essentially an SSD inside a USB 3 enclosure...one that most likely doesn't do TRIM.  I just bought one of these today; I'll have to look around for some software to enable TRIM, if said software exists

Comment: @RussellUhl: You're right, and looks like there's no TRIM support because of the SATA-USB bridge it uses.

Comment: But why would this only occur when transfering files (benchmarks are excellen in HD Tune) and why only now? I've had the USB drive for a year with no problems.

Comment: "I've had the drive for a year with no problems": That's exactly the point.  The usefulness of TRIM only becomes apparent after a certain amount of data has been written to the drive.  You're past that limit, and so now every time you do a write operation, you're actually doing a read-clear-write operation which takes much longer.  My GUESS regarding the benchmark is that they're doing something different in how they write data to the drive.

Comment: There's a light at the end of the tunnel...Sandisk has a lifetime warranty on the drive.  Send it back to them and get a replacement, or demand they get a TRIM utility out for it

Comment: While this might not help your specific problem with your USB drive, I would caution against using your Samsung EVO 840 in our testing. Samsung have recently announced the second firmware update for this SSD due to performance problems: [New Samsung SSD 840 EVO Read Performance Fix Coming Later This Month](http://www.anandtech.com/show/9158/new-samsung-ssd-840-evo-read-performance-fix-coming-later-this-month)

Comment: The SSD is not the problem. When I hook up my external usb 3.0 harddrive and write the same data as I'm using for the thumbdrive, it gets speeds of 90MB/s (the max of the harddrive).